# Excel if with 3 values

Tags: excel, if-statement

I would like to create an excel if-statement that results in 1 of 3 values. In one cell in a column I have a number that is from -500 to 500. In another cell column I like to get "W" if it's above 7, "L" if it's below -7 and "X" if it is between -6 and 6. I have tried with the following:

```
=IF((R68)<-7,"L",IF((R68)>7,"W","X"))
```

but only get W and L.

Comment: [Unable to reproduce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ahtc0.png). Try using `Formulas > Evaluate Formula` to see what is happening.

Comment: the formula is working correctly in my case!

Comment: Got it to work with the following:
=IFS(R20<-64,"L",R20>60,"W",R20<0,"X",R20<60,"X")

Answer (score -1):

Putting your  `(R68)` might be making it negative.

Try removing them:

```
=IF(R68<-7,"L",IF(R68>7,"W","X"))
```

or bracketing whole formula:

```
=IF((R68<-7),"L",IF((R68>7),"W","X"))
```

Good luck!

Comment: They are redundant parentheses, but removing them will not change anything. I agree they should be removed though.